# Timer in codeigniter and ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter, timer

I need timer in codeigniter , mysql and ajax as time in days comes from database for each product.

```
<td id="timer"><?=$data['auction_end_time']?></td>
```

Data comes from database in days and i want to show timer.[**That is the link of my site here you can see**](http://eliquidboxesco.co.uk/aukbid/User/product_info/Properties).

plae guide me ...!

Comment: you need to try jquery timer plugin for that

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have the following php function (this can be improoved)

```
function auction_end_time($future_date) {

    $now = new DateTime();
    $future_date = new DateTime($future_date);

    if($future_date <= $now)
        return 'This offer has expired!';

    $interval = $future_date->diff($now);

   return $interval->format("%a days %h:%i:%s");
}
```

And in your html code

```
<td id="timer"><?=auction_end_time($data['auction_end_time'])?></td>
```

This sollution is static. For dynamic countdown you can use a jquery plugin, I found this [jQuery.countdown plugin](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html)

Please see the example on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/fgpnrsuz/13/)

Comment: I have placed that jsfiddle.net code in my web but error occurs... $this is undefined function ...

Comment: Hello, you need to include the required plugins. On jsfiddle, click on Resources to see what resources are include. In your case, you need only 
 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js

Comment: how i can find the date and time after 3 days?